# Authentication error - Security exception while creating an ISM policy aws elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I'm trying to create an index state management policy in aws opensearch with an user role having cluster_all, indices_all, unlimited permissions. But still i get the error

```
[security_exception] no permissions for [] and User [name=rumuser, roles=[], requestedTenant=]
```

When i try to create the policy with an user having predefined role [all_access](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security-plugin/access-control/users-roles/) it is working fine . I saw in the opensearch [documentation](https://opensearch.org/docs/1.3/im-plugin/security/#basic-permissions) which suggested trying predefined user role index_management_full_access , but could not find it in my kibana console. So i created another user role with the below permissions which failed to work as well.

```
"cluster:admin/opendistro/ism/*",
"cluster:admin/opendistro/transform/*",
"cluster:admin/opendistro/rollup/*",
"indices:admin/opensearch/ism/*"
```

can someone help me here? what additional permissions should i give ?

Answer (score 1):

To use the ISM plugin, your user role needs to be mapped to the all_access role that gives you full access to the cluster. To learn more, see Users and roles.
Ref: https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/im-plugin/ism/index/

[image]